# Local message-queue api/library for Java

Tags: java, message-queue

I'm looking for a message-queue api/library for managing queues locally in java. What do you suggest to me?

I don't want to use a Client/Server architecture, I'd rather do it locally to do not add a failure point. Also, scaling out isn't a necessary for now.

[EDITED]

Is there a Message-Queue API/Library for managing queries locally in java? 
Features: 1) Persistent Queues; 2) Queue management; 3) Thread-safe

Comment: Its not a bad question, we have implemented our own message queues, but this needed some time, to be thread safe in all situations.

Comment: How local? Same JVM? Have you looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/queue.html

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse, I looked the java implementations for queues. But what I'm looking for is more than that. A Library/API with features like queue management, thread safe, persistent queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once upon a time, I looked  for persistent queues and could not find good implementation. I think you have 2 options:

- use a JMS implementation
- use an embedded key-value database with a Map implementation, like [JDBM3](https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3). Emulate a queue as a Map, where id is assigned at the moment of `put` as `previous max id +1`, and `take/poll/get` reads the value with minimal id.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give a look on MapDB (The newer JDBM project)!